# Angular expressions not working in HTML template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I am working on a to-do app using MEAN stack where I am using different view templates. This one is supposed to be loaded on a GET request to #/home/{task_id}

In app.factory I wrote:

```
var t = {
            tasks: [
                //{text: 'Add your first task', note: '', high: true}
            ]
        };

t.getOne = function(id) {
        return $http.get('/home/' + id).then(function(res){
            return res.data;
        });
    };
```

The controller I declared as:

```
app.controller('tasksCtrl',['$scope','tasks','task',function($scope,tasks,task) {
    $scope.task = task;
}]);
```

And in app.config I have (using ui-router):

```
$stateProvider
.state('tasks', {
            url: '/home/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/tasks',
            controller: 'tasksCtrl',
            resolve: {
                task: ['$stateParams','tasks',function($stateParams,tasks) {
                    return tasks.getOne($stateParams.id);
                }]
            }
        });
```

Additionally, in routes/index.js

```
router.route('/home/:task_id')
  .get(function(req, res, next) {
      Task.findById(req.params.task_id).find(function(err, task) {
        if(err){ return next(err); }

        res.json(task);
      });
  })
```

Mongoose schema:

```
var TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    note: String,
    high: Boolean
});
```

I still seem to be missing something as expressions like {{task.text}} are not evaluated

Comment: Are you sure you can do the square bracket syntax in ui.router in `resolve`?

Comment: works fine with and without